# Detect and make links nofollow in author description

Tags: author, nofollow

I have this code in `author.php` file

```
echo $part_cur_auth_obj->description;
```

How can i parse the echo so the links within the author description will have the `rel="nofollow"` attribute set automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add rel="nofollow" to all the links, then you can simply use str_replace():

```
echo str_replace( 
  '<a href=', 
  '<a rel="nofollow" href=', 
  $part_cur_auth_obj->description 
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this simply by javascript code, Add this to your `footer.php` file this will add attribute to all tags.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        $('body > a').attr('rel','nofollow')
    });
```

Or can be done by using **ID's** for **particular tags**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        $('body > a#ID_OF_A_TAG').attr('rel','nofollow')
    });
```

make sure you have pasted correct ID of `<a id="MY_ID">`tag. **MY_ID** in this case

Comment: This did not work :(

Answer (score 0):

You can always benefit from pre-defined WordPress functions, see [`wp_rel_nofollow`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_rel_nofollow/)

```
echo wp_rel_nofollow($part_cur_auth_obj->description);
```

Comment: This changed the description url like this <a href="\&quot;https://example.org\&quot;" rel="\&quot;nofollow\&quot;">example</a>

Comment: `print_r($part_cur_auth_obj->description)` first and share with me the output.